# Is there any way to sort columns of a matrix independently in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm a newbie in R so, I really need some help here. I just want to sort each column independently. Any help is appreciated!

```
 > mat <- matrix(c(45,34,1,3,4325,23,1,2,5,7,3,4,32,734,2),ncol=3)
 > mat
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]   45   23    3
 [2,]   34    1    4
 [3,]    1    2   32
 [4,]    3    5  734
 [5,] 4325    7    2
```

to

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    2
 [2,]    3    2    3
 [3,]   34    5    4
 [4,]   45    7   32
 [5,] 4325    23 734
```

Comment: +1 for clean, clear, simple example provided.  Meanwhile, let me recommend you start reading the R-inferno http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf  and tracking down some tutorial sites like http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html or http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, any tutorials/resources for microarray analysis using R?

Comment: @SteveHwang Check out Bioconductor if you haven't yet: http://www.bioconductor.org/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, there is!

```
apply(mat, 2, sort)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    2
[2,]    3    2    3
[3,]   34    5    4
[4,]   45    7   32
[5,] 4325   23  734
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Quick question. Just messing around with it, if I tried calculating the mean of each row 'mean <- as.matrix(apply(mat, 1, mean))', why do I have to cast it as a matrix but not for the sorting. Is that an inherent property of 'sort' (e.g. keeps data frame as is)?

Comment: @SteveHwang, there is a shortcut for calculating row means, you can use `rowMeans(mat)` this function will return a vector with length equal to the number of rows in your matrix/data.frame

Comment: To close the loop `colMeans`, `colSums`, and `rowSums` work also: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/colSums.html