# sort matrix independently with their corresponding name

Tags: r

I have a matrix like below

```
Name       A           B        C          D       F
117_at   -0.0448    -0.136   -0.2189    0.0637   0.2498
121_at   -0.081      0.1412   0.0464    -0.018  -0.0408
1255_    0.0486     -0.0239   0.0753    -0.067   0.1304
1294_at  -0.109     -0.1266  -0.3023    0.0101   0.0594
1316_at  -0.0389    0.0915   -0.1352    0.1189   0.3161
1320_at  0.0147    -0.0064    0.009     -0.0411 -0.0497
1405_i      0       0.2178   -0.3024    0.2265  -0.0673
1431_at  0.0318     0.0556   -0.0434    -0.018   0.001
1438_at  0.0635     0.2065   -0.2112     0.0856  0.011
1487_at  0.071     -0.1315   0.0263      0.0198  0.0589
```

I want to sort each column independently and save it in a separated file with its corresponding name

If I want to sort my matrix based on each columns separately, I can follow the answer here 
[Is there any way to sort columns of a matrix independently in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140204/is-there-any-way-to-sort-columns-of-a-matrix-independently-in-r)

for example

```
name   A    B    C   
AA     1   -1    86
BB     20   0    -7
CC     30   6    98
DD     5    803  8
```

I expect to have something like the following or each two in a separate file 
for example name and A saved in 1, name and B saved in 2 etc

```
name      A      name    B    name    C
    CC     30     DD     803    CC    98
    BB     20     CC     6      AA    86
    DD     5      BB     0      DD    8
    AA     1      AA     -1     BB    -7
```

Comment: Could you tell us why the solutions in the link doesn't work here?  Can you post the expected output? Perhaps `do.call(cbind,apply(df1[-1], 2, function(x) {ind <- order(x); data.frame(Name=df1[,1][ind], Val=x[ind])}))`

Comment: @akrun  solution is not good because I need the corresponding name for each columns too  I will put an example above

Comment: Please check the solution in the updated comment or `do.call(cbind,Map(function(x,y) data.frame(y,x)[order(x),] , df1[-1], list(df1[1])))` assuming that you have a data.frame instead of matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
 lst <- Map(function(x,y,z) setNames(data.frame(y,x)[order(-x),], 
             c('name', z)), df1[-1], list(df1[1]), names(df1)[-1])
 names(lst) <- NULL
 lst
 #[[1]]
 #  name  A
 #3   CC 30
 #2   BB 20
 #4   DD  5
 #1   AA  1

#[[2]]
#  name   B
#4   DD 803
#3   CC   6
#2   BB   0
#1   AA  -1

#[[3]]
#  name  C
#3   CC 98
#1   AA 86
#4   DD  8
#2   BB -7

 res <- do.call(cbind,lst)
 row.names(res) <- NULL
 res
 #  name  A name   B name  C
 #1   CC 30   DD 803   CC 98
 #2   BB 20   CC   6   AA 86
 #3   DD  5   BB   0   DD  8
 #4   AA  1   AA  -1   BB -7
```

#### Update

Based on the data provided in the link

```
 url <- 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/052e50e7e777849449b3/raw/data_example.txt'
 library(RCurl)
 x <- getURL(url, ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)

 df1 <- read.delim(textConnection(x),header=TRUE, row.names=1, 
            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 dim(df1)
 #[1] 507 990

 lst <- Map(function(x,y,z) setNames(data.frame(y,x)[order(-x),], 
            c('name', z)), df1, list(rownames(df1)), names(df1))

 length(lst)
#[1] 990

 lst[[1]][1:3,]
 #          name levopropoxyphene.HL60.665.5500024030760072207033.A11
 #393   200865_at                                               0.5001
 #323   200795_at                                               0.3676
 #49  200028_s_at                                               0.2452
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(name = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"), 
 A = c(1L, 20L, 
 30L, 5L), B = c(-1L, 0L, 6L, 803L), C = c(86L, -7L, 98L, 8L)),
 .Names = c("name", 
 "A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: what is the x and what is the y ? I have only a matrix and not separated columns, I showed the example matrix I have !

Comment: @Nemo If you have a `matrix`, please do convert it to data.frame as matrix can hold only one class.  Here, the first column is `character`, so it change the whole matrix to character.  `x` and `y` are based on `df1` without the first column and `df1` with only the first column

Comment: your solution messing up my row name , let me upload a real data , so that you have an idea how it looks like

Comment: @Nemo Based on the data you showed, there is no rowname.  Your first column is "Name".  You can use `dput` to show the data.  I am getting the expected output as you showed in the post.

Comment: my data is huge, it is simply not possible to dput it here.   here you can download an example data  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/052e50e7e777849449b3

Comment: @Nemo After you read the `data_example.txt`, did you convert it to matrix?

Comment: please don't use as.matrix or something like that. I don't want to change any value of my matrix. so I load the data by for example data <- read.delim(file="/path to your data",header=TRUE, row.names=1) and then I need to not change any single value of my data

Comment: @Nemo If you are reading it using `read.delim` I think it should be a data.frame.  I don't understand why you are saying it is a matrix.

Comment: my bad! I don't know what is a data frame and what is not a data frame ! I just know my first column is the name of each row and the first row is the name of each column ! how to check which type your data is in R ?

Comment: Yes, this is for sure a data frame type , if the following document is a good document http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame

Comment: @Nemo There are a lot of resources online.  I guess your link would give some insights.  To check the type `is.data.frame(yourdata)` or check `str(data)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply` to produce a list of sorted columns, which would be convenient for subsequent saving individual columns:

```
> z <- lapply(seq(2,ncol(d)), function(i) d[order(d[,i],decreasing = T),c(1,i)])
> z
[[1]]
  name  A
3   CC 30
2   BB 20
4   DD  5
1   AA  1

[[2]]
  name   B
4   DD 803
3   CC   6
2   BB   0
1   AA  -1

[[3]]
  name  C
3   CC 98
1   AA 86
4   DD  8
2   BB -7
```

If you want to put them back together:

```
> do.call(cbind,z)
  name  A name   B name  C
3   CC 30   DD 803   CC 98
2   BB 20   CC   6   AA 86
4   DD  5   BB   0   DD  8
1   AA  1   AA  -1   BB -7
```

`d` is your sample data set, i.e.:

```
d <- structure(list(name = structure(1:4, .Label = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"), class = "factor"), A = c(1L, 20L, 30L, 5L), B = c(-1L, 0L, 6L, 803L), C = c(86L, -7L, 98L, 8L)), .Names = c("name", "A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I liked your solution ! Thanks for your valuable comment. However, it generate a file named z as values which then I cannot perform another analysis on it. I need to do random walks on each column separately but with z, I cannot do it

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. You are going to save columns A, B, etc in separate files, right? And, the names seems to be important here, so you want to save them together with the columns A, B, etc. That means to me that you want to produce a bunch of files each containing two columns, e.g. (name A), (name B), (name C), etc. For this purpose, `z` is great.

Comment: Frankly, I don't see a point of putting back to a single data frame, because there would be no any connection between the columns. In fact, data frame is essentially just a bunch of lists of the same length, so you can just do `data.frame(z)` to represent `z` in the data frame format

Comment: my data is very huge imagine over 40000 rows and something about 2000 columns, I am not planing to put them together. I just want to perform a statistical test (something like this https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/ks.test.html) and get a value for each column . however I cannot do that when i don't see for example  where my first column is

Comment: @Nemo, why not? do `ks.test(z[[1]][,2], z[[2]][,2])`

Comment: I just checked whether the output of your function is what I need by write.table(z, "path to your file/z.txt", sep="\t") and i saw you messed the header name and somehow it is random, please check your code with the data (i put the link above). Related to ks test, you perform it as a two sample test and it is not correct! because as I said each column separately ! however  it is another matter in which i can make another question (to be able to calculate KS for each sorted column at once and save it in a separate file :-D