# Is there a way to sort columns of a matrix independently in data.table package R

Tags: r, data.table

I was reading this post [sort matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140204/is-there-any-way-to-sort-columns-of-a-matrix-independently-in-r) and I was curious if there is something equivalent, i.e., sort columns of a matrix independently in data.table package?

```
mat <- matrix(c(45,34,1,3,4325,23,1,2,5,7,3,4,32,734,2),ncol=3)
```

I would like something:

```
sort <- matrix(c(1,3,34,45,4325,1,2,5,7,23,2,3,4,32,734),ncol=3)
```

Thanks!

Comment: probably a more data.table way but do you just want.. `dt = as.data.table(mat);
dt[,lapply(dt, sort)]`

Comment: It's very easy to sort data.tables using setkey or order.

Comment: the command order does not answer the question. The suggestion of @user20650 does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mat <- matrix(c(45,34,1,3,4325,23,1,2,5,7,3,4,32,734,2),ncol=3)

library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(mat)
#     V1 V2  V3
#1:   45 23   3
#2:   34  1   4
#3:    1  2  32
#4:    3  5 734
#5: 4325  7   2

DT[, lapply(.SD, sort, method = "radix")]
#     V1 V2  V3
#1:    1  1   2
#2:    3  2   3
#3:   34  5   4
#4:   45  7  32
#5: 4325 23 734
```

Comment: I believe this solution is more "data.table" way. Thx!

Comment: Roland ;  curious, as I am not a data.table user, about the benefits in using `lapply(.SD`, rather than `lapply(DT` , as speeds are similar (maybe even slightly slower) although tested on my old lappie. Is it because it is more extendible to examples where `by=` is needed?

Answer (score 1):

You can just `apply`, like so:

```
apply(mat,2,sort)
```